# visual c++ 2010 link against older runtime?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, msvcrt

Sorry if this has been asked.

Just like I can select in C# project that I want it to build for .NET 2.0 runtime, is it possible for native c++ project to be built against older CRT, let's say one from visual studio 2005?

I would like this because I have external SDK that was build with VS2005, but I'd like to use newer IDE.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can build against 2005 and 2008 (think also 2003) as long as they are installed along side vis 2010.

You will need to change The platform Tool set for each project to reflect the one you want to build against (properties -> general -> platform toolset) with v100 being 2010, v90 2008, v80 2005 and so on

Comment: just a note: vis 2010 will upgrade the project files and change the extension so they wont be buildable in older versions after.

Answer (score 4):

In the project settings you can choose MSVC9, but not 8. So you can link against the 2008 redistributables... but not the 2005 ones.